# How to read CSVRecord in apache beam?

Tags: csv, apache-beam, apache-commons-csv

I have a Java Iterable object, Iterable records. And I want to pass it to the Beam pipeline. I tried

PCollection csvRecordPC = p.apply("Create  collection", Create.of(records));

It caused an error

An exception occured while executing the Java class. Can not determine a default Coder for a 'Create' PTransform that has no elements.  Either add elements, call Create.empty(Coder), Create.empty(TypeDescriptor), or call 'withCoder(Coder)' or 'withType(TypeDescriptor)' on the PTransform.

Which Coder should I use? Or how can I write my custom coder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution using FileIO.

```
p.apply(FileIO.match().filepattern(options.getInputFile()))
 .apply(FileIO.readMatches())
 .apply(ParDo.of(new CsvParser()))
```

The CsvPaser() is

```
public class CsvParser extends DoFn<ReadableFile, CSVRecord> {
    @DoFn.ProcessElement
    public void processElement(@Element ReadableFile element, DoFn.OutputReceiver<CSVRecord> receiver) throws IOException {
        InputStream is = Channels.newInputStream(element.open());

        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(is);

        Iterable<CSVRecord> records = CSVFormat.EXCEL.withFirstRecordAsHeader().parse(reader);

        for (CSVRecord record : records) {
            receiver.output(record);
        }
    }
}
```